# GTM: One Tag with multiple triggers, but which one fired?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Let's say,I have one tag in google-tag-manager with 3 triggers assigned to it so that it shows up in google analytics when one of the 3 conditions is met. Is there a way I can find out which one of the 3 triggers actually fired? Up to now I can only see the eventlabel and creating 3 different tags for those 3 triggers doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: Do you want to determine this programmatically during the execution of our tags, or do you want to find out via the debugger ?

Comment: programmatically. I need to collect this data as well.

Answer (score 0):

Alas the tags are not aware which trigger has fired them.

The only workaround I can think of is to have a few variables that check the same conditions that trigger your tags and return a value accordingly.

If your triggers are simple event triggers you can check the {{Event}} variable. If your triggers have additional filters you could use a custom JavaScript variable, something like:

```
function() {
if({{Event}} == "myevent" && {{filterForTrigger1}} == "myValue") {
  return "trigger1";
} else if ({{Event}} == "myevent" && {{filterForTrigger2}} == "myValue") {
 return "trigger2";
}
```

Not really tested, but should work. But there is no way to access the trigger directly in the tag (although I agree that would be a really neat feature and I have already submitted a respective feature request in the GTM forum).